# Does DEF really reduce NOx emissions by 70-90%?

Tags: greenhouse-gas-emissions, emissions, nox, diesel

Is there a discussion about the usefulness of DEF or is it pretty much a clear cut wonder-weapon against emissions?
I read somewhere that NOX can disappear within seconds spontaneously and its not clear if DEF is that much effective because other things have reduced emissions so much already.

This [source](https://www.capitalremanexchange.com/20-facts-you-need-to-know-about-diesel-exhaust-fluid-def/#:%7E:text=DEF%20technology%20has%20been%20used,NOx%20by%2070%25%2D95%25.) claims it reduced NOX by up to 90%.

This graphic implies that actual emissions in the real world aren't that much better (dark grey cloud):

[image]
https://vcoe.at/service/fragen-und-antworten/was-sind-stickoxide-und-wie-schaedlich-sind-sie